# Cannot pass array from checkbox via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble posting array data, can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

```
 function submitchecks() {
    var ids = [];

    $(".question_checked_box").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        ids.push(id);
    });
   alert(ids);
    $.post("at_post.jsp", {pass: "topping", check: "1", top: ids},
            setTimeout(reloader, 2000));

}
```

The alert(id) works, and shows the intended data to be sent to post page, but the other page receives nothing.

I've tried:

```
 String[] tops = request.getParameterValues("top");
```

Shows nothing, returns NULL

I can't get anything via EL either:

```
c:set var="poster" value="${paramValues.top}" scope="session"/>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a handle to a timeout, not a function

Comment: That's just there to reload the div to check the results

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a parameter to `$.post`: it expects the third parameter to be a success callback

Comment: I think it's the name you're using to pass the array. I believe you want to send `"tops[]": ids`

Comment: What @blgt said is also possible. I would move the `setTimeout` out of the `$.post()` too. Or wrap it in a `function(data){}`